# bash Reading array from file

Tags: arrays, bash, file

I've already read a lot of questions concerning reading and writing in ARRAY in bash. I could not find the solution to my issue.

Actually, I've got a file that contains the path of a lot of files.

```
cat MyFile
> ~/toto/file1.txt
> ~/toto/file2.txt
> ~/toto/file3.txt
> ~/toto/file4.txt
> ~/toto/file5.txt
```

I fill an array ARRAY to contain this list:

```
readarray ARRAY < MyFile.txt
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r line
do 
   printf 'TOTO %s\n' "$line"
   ARRAY+=("${line}")
done <MyFile.txt
```

or

```
for line in $(cat ${MyFile.txt}) ; 
    do echo "==> $line"; 
    ARRAY+=($line) ; 
done
```

All those methods work well to fill the ARRAY,

```
echo "0: ${ARRAY[1]}"
echo "1: ${ARRAY[2]}"
> 0: ~/toto/file1.txt
> 1: ~/toto/file2.txt
```

This is awesome. 
but my problem is that if I try to diff the content of the file it does not work, it looks like the it does not expand the content of the file

```
diff ${ARRAY[1]} ${ARRAY[2]}
diff: ~/toto/file1.txt: No such file or directory
diff: ~/toto/file2.txt: No such file or directory
```

but when a print the content:
    echo diff ${ARRAY[1]} ${ARRAY[2]}

> diff ~/toto/file1.txt  ~/toto/file2.txt

and execute it I get the expected diff in the file
   diff ~/toto/file1.txt  ~/toto/file2.txt

```
 3c3
 < Param = {'AAA', 'BBB'}
 ---
 > Param = {'AAA', 'CCC'}
```

whereas if I fill ARRAY manually this way:

```
ARRAY=(~/toto/file1.txt ~/toto/file2.txt)
```

diff works well.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks a lot
Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde expansion does not happen when you use variable substitution from `${ARRAY[index]}`.

Put the full path to the files in MyFile.txt and run your code again.

Comment: I don't think how Cyrus' solution can work, because I don't think the `~` in variables will get expanded.

Comment: Actually it works, if you do not put the `"` around the `${ARRAY[INDEX]}` variable subsititution.  So `diff <(cat ${ARRAY[0]}) <(cat ${ARRAY[1]})`.  That is because `readarray` does not remove the `\n` characters at the end of each line.

Comment: No, `~` is not expanded, and I think your reasoning about `\n` is false too ;-)

Comment: Well try it, I am not reasoning, I experiment and deduce.  with the `"`, I clearly see the `\n` character.  Without it, there are no `\n`.  Or propose a more general solution.  `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: The flaw in the reasoning is that `\n` being there will not cause tilde expansion. So Cyrus' solution cannot work, as long as `~` is in a variable. I would drop your sentence about Cyrus' solution. The rest of the answer (the first sentence and the last sentence) is good.